# customFormat LiveBindings Couldn't find ifthen

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Estou tentando usar um livebindigs invertido, isto é, tenho um campo boolean que vem do banco de dados e tenho que fazer visivel um botão quando este vem false.

Estou colocando no customformat

```
ifthen( owner.fieldbyname('tem_movimentacao').asboolean,false,true );
```

mas é lançado uma exception "EvalError in lpfVisible: Couldn't find ifthen."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função deve ser digitada com letras maiúscula e minúsculas

```
IfThen( owner.fieldbyname('tem_movimentacao').asboolean,false,true );
```

Comment: Uma opção legal para evitar esse tipo de erro futuramente, é você ir em Options > Formatter > Delphi > Capitalization e setar o Capitalization of other words para `As first occurrence`. Assim os proximos casos serão ajustados automáticamentes ao pressionar `Ctrl+D`

Comment: aproveitando o tópico do @HagaHood, tem como tratar o CustomFormat em modo de execução?... criei um tópico para isso mas não sanaram minhas dúvidas. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155978/t%C3%ADtulo-nos-campos-do-listview